# How to fix MariaDB commands out of sync, missing expression near ON?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, stored-procedures, xampp

I have the following procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS find_transactions_past_5_days;

DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE find_transactions_past_5_days (IN input_date DATE) 
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM customer c
            INNER JOIN customer_account ca ON c.customer_id = ca.customer_id
            INNER JOIN account a ON ca.account_id = a.account_id
            INNER JOIN transaction t ON a.account_id = t.account_id;
        END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL find_transactions_past_5_days ("2002-05-22");
```

How when I call it it is giving me the error:

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL query: Copy Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation

#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

, I've tried executing the query without the procedure working fine. However, I cant see what I've done wrong with the stored procedure everything seems to conform with the maria DB documentation. Does anybody know the cause of this issue?

I read online sometimes it if a column name cannot be found, however like I mentioned I did try the select query on its own, which gave me a result with no errors.

Software used:
XAMPP
Mysql

Comment: *I have the following procedure* ?? You do not use input parameter - what's the reason? *it is giving me the error* You can see that the problematic stament is not a part of the procedure. Check your client software, access library/framework and connector for the issue source.

Comment: *Incorrect datetime value: '2021-09-17 24:23:11' for column `transaction`.`transaction_date`*

Comment: Issue not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=e96522079158a53f119447d237dc07a5

Comment: @Akina what seems to be the problem there, is this not the correct format?

Comment: @Akina are you saying the issue is not with the code but with phpmyadmin maybe?

Comment: @Akin  I had to remove this CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'AdminUser#2021'; -- Set secure passwords
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, INDEX, CREATE, ALTER 
 ON bank_assignment TO 'admin'@'localhost';
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'read'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ReadUser#2021';
GRANT SELECT
 ON bank_assignment.* TO 'read'@'localhost'; /* grant to all tables */

-- Show all privileges users have been given
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'admin'@'localhost';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'read'@'localhost'; from the end of my code.

Comment: @Akina Any idea why this is the issue? i need to create users 1 read only, 1 read and write.

Comment: Why pass in a date _and_ call it `past_5_days`?  Does that mean "the 5 days before the input date?  I see no use of `input_date`!

Comment: @RickJames ye sorry added that in later, was trying to figure out what this weird as issue is. Still haven't figured it, it seems it won't let me execute more than 3 select queries at a time!

Answer (score 0):

See [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html#:~:text=If%20you%20get%20Commands%20out,you%20have%20called%20mysql_free_result()%20](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20get%20Commands%20out,you%20have%20called%20mysql_free_result()%20).

That page says that you are fetching the results from the Stored Proc incorrectly.  An SP returns multiple "resultsets" and you need extra client code to look in each resultset to get the rows that were produced.

It looks like your SP has only 1 resultset with some number of rows.

Comment: I am only using this in PHPMyAdmin with XAMPP, so where would i put those commands?

Comment: In the PHP code after processing the results of the select.  Search for examples of that command.

Comment: I never use php code, iam just trying to get it to run in mysql and xampp in the "SQL" section

Comment: OK.  Other APIs have other have similar requirements.  Personally, I don't write an SP to do something simple like a plain SELECT.